# How to checkout submodule in GitHub action?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I've got a repository with a submodule and I'm creating a build when I push to certain branches or tags. The problem I have is that my checkout step cannot access my submodule. The setup is:

1. Both repositories are on GitHub.
2. I'm the owner of both repositories.
3. Both repositories are private.
4. The repositories are only accessible with ssh (https disabled).

I've tried using the GitHub Action `actions/checkout@v2` to no avail. As can be seen below I've tried using the 'ssh-key' option where I've added the public key to the the submodules repositories deploy keys and the private key to the secrets of the repository where I run the action. I get the following error messages:

```
Fetching the repository
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin __myrepo__
  ERROR: Repository not found.
  Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
  Waiting 13 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin __myrepo__
  ERROR: Repository not found.
  Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
  Waiting 19 seconds before trying again
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin __myrepo__
  ERROR: Repository not found.
  Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

I've tried with and without the `ssh-key` as well as with `true` and `recursive` option on `submodules`. The destination of the submodule is in a directory called `src`. The checkout step in my workflow is the following:

```
Step-01:
  runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        submodules: 'true'
        ssh-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_DEPLOY_KEY_IN_SUBMODULE }}
```

The .gitmodules is:

```
[submodule "name"]
    path = src/name
    url = git@github.com:user/repository.git
    branch = master
```

I'm very new to GitHub Actions (CI/CD overall) and not super comfortable with submodules so I may very well have made some basic mistakes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I finally got it working, completely thanks to [this](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/35#issuecomment-580440316).

To clarify the situation SAML SSO is enforced. So instead of using SSH to try and access the submodule I used a personal access token (PAT) where the SSO has been authorized.

What I did:

1. I generated a PAT in account settings.
2. I enabled SSO and authorized it.
3. I added the token in the repository (that wants to access the submodule) secrets.
4. I updated the workflow to the following (just change the ssh-key line).

---

```
Step-01:
  runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
  steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        submodules: 'true'
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Should you add a personal access token to a repository? Couldn't that be a security issue?

Comment: Added to a private repository so should be ok?

Comment: Yes, I would not recommend it for a public repository because it is a potential security issue. Keep private keys private.

Answer (score 7):

I am new to the github actions, and this was the solution I liked.

### 1. Update your CI configuration as follows:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: recursive
    token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
```

### 2. Generate the Personal Access Token (PAT)

Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Tokens (Classic)

Then `Generate New Token` (Classic).

Then use the `repo` checkbox is what I used.  You may be able to get away with less. Then, once it's created, `COPY` the token to the clipboard. Paste it somewhere for safekeeping.

### 3. Store your Personal Access Token (PAT)

1. Go to the repo with the submodule
2. Go to Settings
3. In the side bar, expand Secrets and variables
4. Click actions
5. Add your "New repository secret" PAT_TOKEN, with the value copied from the PAT.

Comment: This fails for me with `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

Comment: I adjusted to work anywhere.  Originally I was on a self hosted system, which it did work on, but It didn't work elsewhere, but now it does.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but since I have a private repo as my submodule, I chose to ignore the submodule option because it needed a PAT with rights on both the main and the submodule repositories. I found it was too much in my case since I have a lot of repos needing the submodule, which would result in either, having a bunch of different PAT for all different main repos or a too broad PAT which would encapsulate all the repos + the submodule.

Instead I created a PAT with only the submodule rights and I use the following workflow syntax to make it work in all my main repos:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: org/submodule-repo
          path: submodule-repo
          token: ${{ secrets.SUBMODULE-PAT }}
```

Comment: I did this too but note it has a shortcoming depending on how you do things. This will checkout the default branch of the submodule as opposed to choosing the SHA of the pointer "submodule-repo".

Personally I think the right approach is to make a PAT w/ superset access. I don't that is all that insecure. I'd use a service account user or a fine-grained PAT with (I believe) the "Contents" privilege.  https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Answer (score 1):

Got it working as well, mostly thanks to [@Nelumbo answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091631/4416181).

Few things to keep in mind if you use new [fine-grained Personal Access Tokens (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token):

1. Make sure that to add permission to access the parent repo as well, not only submodule repos, because when `token` param to `checkout` step this token will be used to checkout everything, not only submodules.
2. The token is good for a year max, so be prepared that the issue will come back, set a reminded and do not freak out.
3. The token only needs to have read-only permissions to Contents and Metadata (from Repository permissions), and none of the Account permissions.